# Access viewcontroller from button

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have ButtonClass which has buttonTapped method implemented.

The button itself is  on the view. I need to add an extra layer when the button is pressed but I don't have access to self in the ButtonClass because self is a button not the view... Basically I need to access self.view found in the viewController but that's another class. If I create an new instance like so viewController() it won't help because it wont' be the same instance.

Comment: We won't understand your question if you won't put more details like code, storyboard design etc.

Comment: You can access your buttons `superview` chain but it would be better to use a delegation pattern to invoke a method in the view controller from the button or put the action handler in the view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding the buttonTapped method from the custom button class then you need to create a delegate, and call the delegate method when the user the buttonTapped method is called.

In your custom button class

```
protocol YourCustomButtonDelegate {
    func changeSomethingInTheView()
}

class YourCustomButtonClass {

    var delegate: YourCustomButtonDelegate?

    func buttonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.changeSomethingInTheView()
        }
    }
}
```

And in the ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: YourCustomButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.delegate = self
    }

    func changeSomethingInTheView() {
        // write your code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @J. Koush, Thank you for your answer, I tried to implement it but it seems that  "if let delegate = delegate {"  fails because it  complains delegate is an unresolved identifier...

Comment: @Marin You need you create delegate variable in your custom button class like this `var delegate: YourCustomButtonDelegate?`

Comment: "button.delegate = self"  throws  'cannot assign viewController to type 'buttonDelegate"   ....

Comment: I thought you knew how to work with delegates, now I've updated the code @Marin.

Comment: Thank you J. Koush!  I'll go over your code to fully understand delegates, as the examples online do not clarify it completely.  Thank you once again :)